# How to add row details in JSF data table?

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatable, row

I need to add '+' icon in every JSF dataTable row. On Click, of that icon, row should expand to show associated details about object in that row. I need to know, whether there is already something existing of this nature in JSF?

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Please let me know, is anyone has idea about it. Just for FYI, I am using data table from tomahawk as of now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplished this using varDetailToggler of t:dataTable since tomahawk was already a part of project and then using detailStamp facet to specify the component to be shown as row details. Code looks like this:

```
<t:dataTable var="node"
    border="1"
    value="#{tableDataModel}"
    varDetailToggler="detailToggler">
    <t:column >
        <h:commandLink rendered="#{detailToggler.currentDetailExpanded}" action="#{detailToggler.toggleDetail}">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/minus.png" style="border:0" />
        </h:commandLink>
        <h:commandLink rendered="#{!detailToggler.currentDetailExpanded}" action="#{detailToggler.toggleDetail}">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/plus.png" style="border:0" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </t:column>
    <t:column >
    ....
    </t:column>
    <t:column >
    ....
    </t:column>
    <f:facet name="detailStamp">
                <h:outputText value="Row details here...Can be any component"/>
    </f:facet>
</t:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go for PrimeFaces for various components,

As for your current need check out [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf)

Comment: Thanks Jitesh. Unfortunately, I don't want to add new library just for one component. I am already using components from richfaces and tomahawk.

Comment: I found reply of BalusC on similar requirement which seems to be worth a shot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133985/expand-collapse-of-table-rows-in-datatable-jsf

Comment: @AmitGupta RichFaces already handles this using [`<rich:collapsibleSubTable>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks but it provides enitrely different functionality. What I need is when user click on particular row with data entries, it shows up panel below with associated information in it which need not necessary be table. I've provided an example link in question.

Comment: @AmitGupta that can be achieved using `<ui:repeat>` to have the table and [`<rich:collapsiblePanel>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=collapsiblePanel&skin=blueSky). Do not think that `<h:dataTable>` or `<rich:dataTable>` are the only ways to create a `<table>` HTML element in JSF.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi for the suggestion. I'll definitely try this out.